# Google analytics - Data Studio, show conversion rate if a page was viewed

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have our E-commerce Conversion Rate all set up and looking good in GA. I want to view the conversion rate of people who have viewed a specific page and add this information to a Datastudio report...

I have the metric in Datastudio as "E-commerce Conversion Rate" everything looks good and the data matches GA, however, I tried filtering based on the dimension "page" contains "/pageurl" but I don't get a valid result... What am I doing wrong?

Like I said I just want to see the conversion rate of users who have visited a certain page during their journey...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that the e-commerce conversion rate is not a pageview-level metric. So, when you try to add on a filter to contain users that went to a certain page, it won't work correctly.

It's like if you try to go into the All pages report in GA, you'll notice there is only a *page value* metric but no conversion rate.

You have two options depending on the report you are trying to make. You can change the filter to be *landing page* rather than just *page* or you can create a custom segment in GA that is a session containing a view of the particular page you are looking for.